# R - format POSIXct as date in list

Tags: r, database

Im using code bellow for loading data from database

```
lns <- tbl(connection, "table") %>%
    filter(client_id %in% client_ids$client_id) %>%
    select(
      date,
      client_id,
      contract_number
    ) %>%
    collect()
```

What I need is to reformat my date in POSIXct to Date. That means "1970-01-01 03:03:02" to "1970-01-01" I need to do that before collect() step.

I usauly use for it mutate(date = as.Date(date)) but for some reason code below gives me this error

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) :    Failed to prepare
>   query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS" LINE 2: ..._cmc_date",
>   "in_deco", "terms_and_conditions_id", AS.DATE("e...
>                                                                ^

Here is the code:

```
lns <- tbl(connection, "table") %>%
    mutate(test = as.Date(entity_created)) %>% 
    filter(client_id %in% client_ids$client_id) %>%
    select(
      date,
      client_id,
      contract_number
    ) %>%
    collect()
```

Comment: Please provide sample data to correctly figure out what the problem is. `dput(yourdf)`. Otherwise,we cannot test or see what's wrong by just lookinng at the code.

Comment: We've got (mostly) plenty of info in the question itself to pose some remedies. You're using a `dplyr` in a DB context. Knowing how you got `connection` might be nice since `dplyr`/`dbplyr` uses various heuristics & embedded rules to convert `dplyr` verbs to SQL which then goes to the db. It would appear that your database provides no hints (via the driver) as to what to do when the `dplyr` SQL translation layer sees `as.Date()` & — as such — is just passing it through to the back end db. In place of `collect()` put `dbplyr::sql_render() %>% as.character() %>% cat()` to see the SQL being sent.

Comment: Alternately, sine you're not doing any other operations with `entity_created` in that pipe chain, you can move the `mutate()` line to after the `collect()` line.